# Script to backup data to specific USB Drive

Tags: powershell

I have a script and I was looking to have it reviewed to see where I should improve it.

**Our need:** We need to backup a folder every day to a specific USB drive. There may be multiple USB drives plugged into the computer. We need to ensure that it is only backing up to a specific drive.

**Code:**

```
function ex{exit}

#####################################
### Check PC for backup USB Drive ###
#####################################

$diskdrive = Get-WmiObject win32_diskdrive

foreach($drive in $diskdrive){
  $partitions = Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($drive.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"

    foreach($part in $partitions){
        $name=$drive.model
        $vols = Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($part.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"

    foreach($vol in $vols){
       If($name -eq "General UDisk USB Device" ){
       $USBDisk=$vol.name
       }
     }
  }
}

if ( $USBDisk -eq $null ) {
[void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Custom Backup, Please Plug-In the USB Drive","USB Drive not found")
ex
}


###########################################
### Purge USB for data over 90 days old ###
###########################################

$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)

Get-ChildItem -Path $USBDisk -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

# Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
Get-ChildItem -Path $USBDisk -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

#########################
### Backup Custom DBs ###
#########################

# Import Assemblies
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load("System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")

$date = Get-Date -Format MMMM.d.yyyy
$backupFolder = "Backup_" + "$date" 

if ( $USBDisk -eq $null ) {
#[void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("No USB Disk Found, Please Plug-In the USB Drive","USB Drive not found")
} 
else {
$Usbfreedisk =  ((Get-WmiObject win32_logicalDisk  | where { $_.DeviceID -eq $USBDisk }).FreeSpace /1gb -as [INT])
$FPBackup= Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Folder" | Measure-Object -property length -sum
[int]$DataFilesize = ($FPBackup.sum / 1GB )

if ( $Usbfreedisk -lt $DataFilesize ) {
    [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Your $USBDisk Drive don't have enough space, for backup we need $DatafileSize GB of free space.","Not Enough space")
    }
else {
    $testfolder = Test-Path "$USBDisk\$backupFolder" 
  if ( $testfolder -eq $true ) {
  [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You already have backup folder $USBDisk\$backupFolder Please rename it or delete it before running the backup ","Backup Folder Exists") 
  }
 else{ 
  mkdir "$USBDisk\$backupFolder"
  Robocopy "C:\Folder"  "$USBDisk\$backupFolder\CYA" /mir /r:2 /w:3
    if ($lastexitcode -eq 0){
            write-host "Robocopy succeeded"
            }
            else{
            write-host "Robocopy failed with exit code:" $lastexitcode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if anyone needs any clarification on anything.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What happens when Robocopy fails for reasons you haven't caught? Is this acceptable? You spell `usbdisk` with different capitals at times, is this on purpose? What do you think of this practice yourself?

Comment: @Mast Thank you very much for your response! The Robocopy is a good point. I can give that some consideration and make modifications. The `USBDisk` typos were not on purpose and I have updated them in my script.

Comment: @Mast I just added in a catch for a failure. I'll have to consider what we would like to do if it does fail, but I figured that could be a start.